# How to extract Javascript content into python?

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to extract the javascript content from this site: https://js.tokopedia.com/productstats/check?pid=2156146

it's a very simple javascript information that i need to put inside my Python code, basically I have a dictionary of items that I have converted from JSON to my python code from the same website. I want to do the same thing with Javascript and convert it to python, but so far the solution I found is for me to try Selenium which I am familiar with but Selenium is slow. This task requires me to extract many information from different uri.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
for x in range (0, 3):
with opener.open('https://ace.tokopedia.com/search/v2.6/product?shop_id=2156146&ob=11&rows=80&start='+ str(x*80) +'&full_domain=www.tokopedia.com&scheme=https&device=desktop&source=shop_product') as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    for produk in data['data']:
        k+=1
        pid = produk['id']
        my_url = opener.open('https://js.tokopedia.com/productstats/check?pid=' + str(pid))
        url3 = json.loads(my_url.read().decode())
        print(k, produk['id'], produk['name'], produk['price'], url3['item_sold'])
```

I'm trying to do the same thing with json.loads which of course didn't work because it's in javascript.

I forgot what i did, but I think when I used requests I got this intstead:`<addinfourl at 2309306503576 whose fp = <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x00000219AD61AA20>>`

Help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The content is not a JSON string, but contains a JSON string you need to extract first. For instance, you can split the string at the "(" position:

```
content = """show_product_stats({"item_sold":0, "success":0,"reject":0})"""
frag = content[content.index("(") + 1:-1]
```

The convert the JSON string to a Python object:

```
import json

obj = json.loads(frag)
print(obj)
# -> {'item_sold': 0, 'success': 0, 'reject': 0}
```